# Ec2 or Azure with spring boot

Tags: mysql, azure, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I have a CRUD application in Spring Boot. This app only has a REST API, no UI.

Now days I want to publish my app in EC2 or Azure but don't know which package I will choose ex. There is t2.large, t2.micro etc. in EC2.

I only have REST call so which package should I choose?

I am also using MySQL in my application.

Comment: I would say to utilize both free trials so long as you think your applications are "simple", in the sense that you don't rely much on other cloud services. Using both,  it will probably be easier in the long-run to make the decision based whichever cloud services you require. Even though I prefer Azure, I think AWS would better suite your needs since it is easier (or at least possible) to integrate databases other that MSSQL. And, from a learning perspective,it's easier to work with SSH to tap into your running instance.

Answer (score 0):

I've just finished a project, a CRUD Application is Spring Boot, there was no views. I used an EC2 instance, AWS free tier t2.micro. This lasts for about year if you are just starting a new account. You can use RDS for your mysql database and connect it through you applications.properties.

Hope this helps!